# Absolute address of function in object file

Tags: c, arm, cortex-m, machine-code

I have ARM Cortex-M object file (.o) in which I have following code: `BL $testFunc`. In the same object file I can also find a implementation of the `testFunc`. Can I get the absolute address that the call will be made during the program execution? I have ONLY the object file

Comment: Object files do not contain absolute addresses. Absolute addresses are only available after linking.

Comment: Actually, @Tarik, that is not exactly true. In fact, an absolute address can only be known at execution time, because it depends on where the O/S loads it into memory.

Comment: @SGeorgiades I'm using a bare metal ARM Cortex-M. Isn't it defined by the linker script?

Comment: @SGeorgiades :  Except this is a Cortex-M MCU, so the executable is normally explicitly  located by the linker and written to flash ROM.

Comment: @SGeorgiades Well, what you said is indeed what are learned back in the late 80's. We implemented an assembler, linker and loader for a theoretical machine. However, I hesitated to mention runtime because the executable is loaded starting at virtual memory 0. I am not knowledgeable enough to tell if this implies static addresses during linking. What do you think?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$testFunc` is an unresolved link.  You have to link the object file with the C runtime and MCU initialisation code along with any other dependencies (libraries separate object modules) before an absolute address is determined.

The compiler has no awareness of the memory environment of the target. The linker takes the separate object code modules and the *linker script* (which defines the memory map) and resolves links and locates code and data.

The linker can output a MAP file that will include the absolute addresses of all externally linker code and data items.